# Fade Header on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website for a friend (https://www.nicoledavis.org) and have not been able to get the code right in order to make the top photo fade to black when scrolled. The idea is to have the entire top photo completely fade to black before the "Background Info" appears on the screen. Any help is much appreciated!

I used the exact code setup (copy/pasted) from here: https://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/21 or see below:

jQuery:

```
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#blackOverlay').css('opacity', 
            currentScrollTop/$('#blackOverlay').height());
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
    #blackOverlay {
      background-color: #000;
      opacity: 0.0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="blackOverlay"></div>
```

The effect I'm seeing in the JSFiddle example is exactly what I'm hoping the website header does on the website I'm working on, but the code doesn't seem to have the same effect on my site. I'd also like for the speed of the fade effect to be increased, but have not yet been successful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you have already tried. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JeffMergler Please see my reviewed post to include additional details and specific codes used.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<html>
<style>
  .headerClass {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
</style>

<h1 id="header">header</h1>

<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
      fadeText()
    };

    function fadeText() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1) {
        document.getElementById("header").classList.add("headerClass");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("header").classList.remove("headerClass");
      }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

You say you've tried some code, but it didn't work. May I take a look at it?

Comment: Please see my reviewed post to include additional details and specific codes used.